# Need to know if a number is divisible after an operation

Tags: c, virtual-memory, integer-division

I have a number on which I perform a specific operation
I want to make sure that the number is still divisible after the operation.

Let's say I have an integer x which is divisible by PAGE_S

does this produces an integer which is also divisible by PAGE_S ?

```
x^ ~(PAGE_S-1);
```

so `(x % PAGE_S) == ( (x^ ~(PAGE_S-1)) % PAGE_S)` ?
As far as I tested, it works, but I need to understand why...

p.s this is part of a code of translating virtual memory addresses to physical addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only if `PAGE_S` is a power of two.

If `PAGE_S` is a power of two (say, 2<sup>k</sup>), then its binary representation is a 1 followed by k 0s. So, `PAGE_S-1` will be k 1s in binary, so `~(PAGE_S-1)` is all 1s followed by k 0s.

The xor operation (^) will flip any bits of the first operand for which the corresponding bit in the second operand is 1; for example, 101101 ^ 111000 is 010101 because the first three bits are flipped.

Since `x` is divisible by `PAGE_S`, the last k bits must be zero. Since the last k bits of `~(PAGE_S-1)` are also zero, the last k bits of `x^~(PAGE_S-1)` are zero so it is divisible by `PAGE_S`. This also inverts all the other bits of `x`.